# Change LoginPath without ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core

[Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

The login file is located at `Pages/Account/Login.cshtml`.

I wish to change to `Pages/Index`, but I am not able to change the `LoginPath` after trying various methods that I found using Google.

Comment: I have added this line as a temporary solution until I find a permanent fix. ``services.AddRazorPagesOptions(o => { o.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Index", "/Account/Login"); });``

Comment: Chage like below:`services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>{options.LoginPath = "/Index";});`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with adding the following snippet inside the ConfigureServices method. It has to be placed behind your call of AddAuthentication().

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(cookie =>
{
     cookie.LoginPath = "/Index";
});
```